Highcharts organizational chart export font size
I am using highcharts to renderorganizational chart for our company and in my web browser it works fine but when I export to pdf i loose text in my nodes.
I have tried numerous approaches with no luck.
This is my fiddle:
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        height: 200,width:400,
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: ' Ledning'
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormat: '{add index 1}. {toNode.name}' +
                '{#if (ne toNode.name toNode.id)}, {toNode.id}{/if}, ' +
                'reports to {fromNode.id}'
        }
    },
  plotOptions: { 
    series: { 
      cursor: 'pointer',
      point: { 
        events: { 
          click: function() {
            location.href = 'http://google.com';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

    series: [{
        type: 'organization',
        name: 'Factory',
        keys: ['from', 'to'],
        nodes: [
                {id: 'AAA', title:'Important person 1', name: 'John Doe',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'BBB', title:'Important person 2', name: 'Jane Doe',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'CCC', title:'Important person 3', name: 'Matt Black',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'DDD', title:'Important person 4', name: 'Millie Liter',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'EEE', title:'Important person 5', name: 'Nick Some',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'FFF', title:'Important person 6', name: 'Wednesday Parker Hutchinson',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'GGG', title:'Important person 7', name: 'Wendy McDonald',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'HHH', title:'Important person 8', name: 'Natalie Porter',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'III', title:'Important person 9', name: 'Sir Donald Ravensburger',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'JJJ', title:'Important person 10', name: 'Mick Dundee',width:120, height:100},
                {id: 'KKK', title:'Important person 10', name: 'Nicki Wicki',width:120, height:100},
        ],      
        data: [
            ['KKK','FFF'],
            ['KKK','JJJ'],
            ['KKK','BBB'],
            ['KKK','III'],
            ['KKK','EEE'],
            ['KKK','DDD'],
            ['KKK','CCC'],
            ['KKK','GGG'],
            ['KKK','AAA'],
            ['KKK','HHH'],
        ],
        levels: [{
            level: 0,
            color: 'silver',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 1,
            color: 'blue',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'white'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 2,
            color: 'blue',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'white'
            },
        }, {
            level: 3,
            color: 'blue',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'white'
            },
        }, {
            level: 4,
            color: 'blue'
        }],     
        colorByPoint: false,
        layout: 'hanging',
        color: '#007ad0',
        dataLabels: {
            color: 'white', style : { fontSize:'25px' }
        },
        borderColor: 'white',
        nodeWidth: 'auto'
    }],
    tooltip: {
        outside: true
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        allowHTML: true,
            menuItemDefinitions: {
                downloadPDF: {
                        onclick: function() {
                            this.exportChart({
                                    type: 'application/pdf',
                                    width: null
                            });
                        },
                }
            },
        sourceWidth: 2000,
        sourceHeight: 700,
        chartOptions: {
             nodes: {
                     width: '400px',
                 title: {
                     style: {
                         fontSize:'8px'
                     }
                 },
                 name: {
                     style: {
                         fontSize:'8px'
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
});

(https://jsfiddle.net/pju2bfg7/)
Sorry about the formatting for the web view, I had to squeez to reach the export menu in fiddle, the format is not important it is the export to pdf that is important.
Have anyone been able to change the font size for the nodes text when exporting?
/R
I have tried using exporting.chartOptions without any luck!

You need to set the chart options for exporting at the same level as the non-exported chart. For example:
  exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    allowHTML: true,
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        width: 2000,
        height: 700
      },
      series: [
        {
          dataLabels: {
            style: {
              fontSize: "12px"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8uhkjset/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization
